# Recursive version of the function failing while being decorated

Tags: python

I have the following code, and for some reason the recursive version the function being decorated is failing with the below exception

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'`

Here is my code

```
def deco_func(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('Decorating')
        res = f(*args)
        print(res)
        print('Done !!')

    return wrapper

@deco_func
def fact(n):
    # res = 1
    # for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    #     res = res * i
    #return res
    if n > 0:
        return n * fact(n-1)
    else:
        return 1

fact(5)
```

Another thing is observed is that statement `print('Decorating')` is also running every time the the call to function `f` is made.

This is driving me crazy and I am getting lost here because as soon as function `fact` is decorated it gets the value of `wrapper object` and when we call `fact(6)` it is actually calling `wrapper(6)`, further inside it's body `wrapper` function is calling the function object `f` which is actually the original `fact`, confusing part is how and why the call to `f(*args)` is sending the control back to `wrapper` function and why it prints the print statement every time, because the thing is `f` comes from enclosing scope and should retain its value since python creates a closure for it.

Second thing, I tried debugging the code and once the value of n reaches 0, it returns value 1 to `res` and then out of nowhere `n` again becomes 1 and it throws the exception at below line

`return n * fact(n-1)`

Can anyone please explain what exactly is happening here and what exactly I am missing here conceptually !!!

Comment: call to f(*args) calls the fact() and inside the fact it calls the wrapper(n-1),now i do not understand why return is creating a prob here, bcoz inside the wrapper control never goes beyond res = f(*args), so a final call like f(0) would result in res = 5*4*3*2*1, and then once res has been calculated control should go to next statement.So i am nt understanding why NOT having the return statement in wrapper is creating problem when the return would only execute once res has been calculated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `return(res)` to your wrapper function. Any python function that fails to execute a `return` statement implicitly returns `None`.

When you execute the call:

```
    return n * fact(n-1)
```

This is, by virtue of your decorator, really:

```
return n * wrapper(n-1)
```

But, since `wrapper()` returns `None` the statement is like:

```
return n * None
```

Thus, your error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Here is your decorator, fixed.

```
def deco_func(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('Decorating')
        res = f(*args)
        print(res)
        print('Done !!')
        return res       # <--- ADD THIS LINE

    return wrapper
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but i still don't understand why it calls back the wrapper function, because shouldn't it just remember the fact coming from enclosing scope. And it is because of this, that print statement is running every time.

Comment: It calls the wrapper function again because you've implemented a recursive algorithm. Note that `fact()` calls `fact()` recursively. Since `fact()` is decorated, each recursive call invokes the wrapper.

Comment: call to f(*args) calls the fact() and inside the fact it calls the wrapper(n-1),now i do not understand why return is creating a prob here, bcoz inside the wrapper control never goes beyond res = f(*args), so a final call like f(0) would result in res = 5*4*3*2*1, and then once res has been calculated control should go to next statement.So i am nt understanding why NOT having the return statement in wrapper is creating problem when the return would only execute once res has been calculated,

Comment: Hello, can you please explain this in a bit detail, i am trying very hard to understand from last 2 days but could not.... I would really appreciate your help and support here.